# stripping out the admin out of the url

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i do window.loaction i get

```
 pathname: "/shopper/admin/index.php"
```

i really need

```
 pathname: "/shopper/index.php"
```

becuase when i do the jquery load i need the admin out of the url

```
$('.replace').load('index.php?route=module/cart/ajax_sub?category_id=12');
```

Comment: Can't you just use an absolute url? `$('.replace').load('/shopper/index.php?route=module/cart/ajax_sub?category_id=12');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var my_location = window.location.pathname.replace('admin/', '');
```

EDIT

Answer (score 2):

you can do with simple replace:

```
pathname = "/shopper/admin/index.php"
pathname = pathname.replace('/admin', ''); // replace with nothing
// would be: "/shopper/index.php"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the section of the path by using the replace function:

```
var part = '/admin';
window.location.replace(part, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

try the following to strip the "/admin" from the URL

```
pathname: "/shopper/admin/index.php".replace("\/admin","")
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/6tGgj/1/)